# Assign a value to a return variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

It is probably a fundamental question, but I am not sure what keywords to use to search for it.

**Is it possible to assign a value to a return variable** in vb.net, something like that:

my.settings.a, my.settings.b, my.settings.c are already set up in the settings as strings

```
Private Function getVar(ByVal index as integer)
 if index = 0 then
   return my.settings.a
 elseif index = 1 then
   return my.settings.b
 else
   return my.settings.c
 end if
End Function

Private Function setVar()
 getVar(0) = "apple"     'that would equal to my.settings.a = "apple"
 getVar(1) = "pear"      'that would equal to my.settings.b = "pear"
 getVar(10) = "banana"   'that would equal to my.settings.c = "banana"
End Function
```

The code above is not correct but is to explain what I'd like to do.

Comment: VB.Net has a gimmick where you can make a property with a parameter.  `Property MyValue(index as integer) As String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean that you'd like to return a reference to the specific property of `My.Settings` dependent upon the number index you specify.

However, you could easily set the values by expanding your function to do something like:

```
Private Sub setVar(ByVal index as integer, ByVal value As Object)
    If index = 0 Then
        My.Settings.a = value
    ElseIf index = 1 then
        My.Settings.b = value
    Else
        My.Settings.c = value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub setVar()
    setVar(0, "apple")
    setVar(1, "pear")
    setVar(10, "banana")
End Sub
```

This way, to set the value of index 1, you would specify:

```
setVar(1, "pear")
```